# Asymptotic behaviour of an integral

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $I(r)$ be

$$\frac{1}{4\pi^2 r}\int_{m}^{\infty} d\rho \frac{\rho e^{-\rho r}}{\sqrt{\rho^2-m^2}}$$

How can I show that

$$I(r) \sim  e^{-mr} $$ for $r\to\infty$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we make the substitution $\rho = m + v^2$, the the integral becomes

$$I(r)=\frac{1}{4 \pi^2 r} 2 \, e^{-m r} \int_0^{\infty} dv \frac{v^2+m}{\sqrt{v^2+2 m}} e^{-r v^2}$$

As $r \to \infty$, the integral is increasing dominated by its contribution near $v=0$, i.e., $v \in [0,\epsilon]$, which would mean that $r = O(\epsilon^{-1/2})$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.  Then, when $m>0$:

$$I(r) \sim \frac{1}{4 \pi^2 r} 2 \, e^{-m r} \sqrt{\frac{m}{2}} \int_0^{\epsilon} dv \, e^{-r v^2} \sim \frac{1}{4 \pi^2 r} 2 \, e^{-m r} \sqrt{\frac{m}{2}} \int_0^{\infty} dv \, e^{-r v^2}$$

Thus, we have the result

$$I(r) \sim \frac{e^{-m r}}{4 \pi^2 r^{3/2}} \sqrt{\frac{\pi m}{2}} \quad (r \to \infty)$$

Comment: Hi, thanks! very clear as usual. Only one thing remains obscure to me: which was the motivation for the substitution?

Comment: @Nivalth: "as usual"?  hah, you are too kind!  The motivation was to get rid of any trace of the integration variable from a denominator, as well as to use a Laplace's Method-type argument.

Answer (score 2):

First let us change the variables $\rho=ms$, so that
$$I(r)=\frac{m}{4\pi^2 r}\int_1^{\infty}\frac{se^{-mr s}ds}{\sqrt{s^2-1}}$$

Now the rough idea is as follows. Because of the exponential factor, we expect that the main contribution to the integral will come from a small vicinity of $s=1$, so small that the function $\frac{s}{\sqrt{s+1}}$ can be considered constant on it (equal to $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$). On the other hand, this interval (denote it by $[1,1+\Delta]$) should be much bigger than the inverse $(mr)^{-1}$ of our large parameter. So we have
\begin{align}
I(r)\approx \frac{m}{4\pi^2 r}\int_1^{1+\Delta}\frac{e^{-mr s}}{\sqrt{s-1}}\cdot\frac{s}{\sqrt{s+1}}\cdot ds\approx 
\frac{m}{4\sqrt{2}\,\pi^2 r}\int_1^{1+\Delta}\frac{e^{-mr s}}{\sqrt{s-1}} ds=\\=\frac{m e^{-mr}}{4\sqrt{2}\,\pi^2 r}\int_0^{\Delta}\frac{e^{-mr t}}{\sqrt{t}} dt=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}\,\pi^2 r}\cdot\frac{m e^{-mr}}{\sqrt{mr}}\int_0^{\Delta/mr}\frac{e^{-u}}{\sqrt{u}} dt\approx\\ \approx
\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}\,\pi^2 r}\cdot\frac{m e^{-mr}}{\sqrt{mr}}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-u}}{\sqrt{u}} dt= \frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}\,\pi^2 r}\frac{m e^{-mr}}{\sqrt{mr}}\cdot\sqrt{\pi}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{{1 \over 4\pi^{2}r}\int_{m}^{\infty}\dd\rho\, {\rho\expo{-\rho r} \over \root{\rho^{2} - m^{2}}}}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\rho\ =\ m\cosh\pars{\theta}}{=}\,\,\,\,&\
{m \over 4\pi^{2}r}\int_{0}^{\infty}\cosh\pars{\theta}
\expo{-mr\cosh\pars{\theta}}\,\,\,\dd\theta
\\[5mm] \stackrel{{\rm as}\ r\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,&\
{m \over 4\pi^{2}r}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{-mr\bracks{1 + {\theta^{2} \over 2}}}\,\,\,\dd\theta
\\[5mm] = &\
{m \over 4\pi^{2}r}\expo{-mr}\root{2 \over mr}
{\root{\pi} \over 2}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{{\root{2} \over 8}\,{m^{2} \over \pi^{3/2}}\,
\color{red}{\expo{-mr} \over \pars{mr}^{3/2}}} \\ &
\end{align}